# jQuery UI Dialog - Reset form value & validation after dialog close (x) or cancel

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-ui-dialog

I got my form in jQuery ui dialog and I apply client-side validation in it. I wish to clear all input values as well as any validation messages the once user clicks (x) to close the dialog or the "Cancel" button, before submitting the form.

I tried to include a clear form function in the "close" event, but it didn't work:

```
 //Load food form into dialog
    var controllerUrl = '/Stock/GetFoodForm';
    var $createdialog = $('#createfooddialog').load(controllerUrl).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Create Food',
        modal: true,
        width: 'auto',
        close: clear()
    });
```

The clear function is used in the function in jquery.form.js plugin:

```
// Function to clear form data
function clear() {
    $('#formData').resetForm();
    $('.validation-summary-valid').val("");
}
```

Any idea how can I clear everything in the form once the user closes the dialog even though the form is not submitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `clear` instead of `clear()`.

Comment: Or `close: function() { clear(); }`, though `close: clear` is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Never realize made such a mistake.. and I modified the clear function to clear the validation message:
function clear() {
        // Clear all input value
        $('#formData').resetForm();

        // Clear the validation summary message
        $('.validation-summary-errors span').remove();

        // Clear the name error message
        $('.field-validation-error span').remove();

        // Clear the amount error message
        $('.field-validation-valid span').remove();
        $('#formData').find('input').removeClass('input-validation-error');